How to check css property already present in an element in javascript
I have a div
<div id="myDiv" style="border:1px solid white; width:20px; height: 100px">....</div>

now in Js, if border css property is already present I need to remove that by using
let element = document.getElementById("myDiv")
element.style.removeProperty("border");

if border css property not present, need to add
let element = document.getElementById("myDiv")
element.style.border = '1px solid white'

but, How to check whether the css property(border) exists or not in element(myDiv)

Consider using proper css classes instead of styles, then you can easily check for a className and toggle it.

using if(element.style.border) {} to check for it's existence. Even cssText works fine.

@fdomn-m I was doing that but I wondered why no one have ever came across this. which is time saver in many critical situations. hence, asked the question.

There's a difference between checking an inline style and checking if an element has a styled added by a class.  "time saver" seems unlikely if you're using already classes.

@fdomn-m kindly guide me, if the question is not so relevant in present tech world. I would like to delete this question.

to be clear: your question is fine.   @OMiShah 's comment above should be an answer. My first comment is just a suggestion - you've already considered it so no longer relevant (left the comment otherwise others would just make the same suggestion).   To clarify my second comment: If you are using classes and want to check that the class has applied a border, then it's very different from if an inline style has applied a border - so more of an advisory for anyone wanting that scenario and wondering why .style.border isn't working.  But that's not this question.

@OMiShah element.style.border will give empty string value if not present. and this is enough to check whether element present or not.

This might be an xy problem, however its often useful to be able to check details on the current computed css. You're probably looking for the Window method getComputedStyle().
Something to keep in mind, this will not let you know if you set the style, just what is currently rendered by the browser. A good idea is to check if it is your desired style, if not, apply your desired style.
Enjoy this small demo of getComputedStyle.


const box = document.querySelector(".moving-box");

const centerBox = () => {
  box.style.cssText = `
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
  `;
};

const alignBoxToTopLeft = () => {
  box.style.cssText = `
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    translate: unset;
  `;
};

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(box);
  const currentTopValue = compStyles.getPropertyValue("top");
  if (currentTopValue === "0px") {
    centerBox();
  } else {
    alignBoxToTopLeft();
  }
});
.moving-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 20pt;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  user-select: none;
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
<div class="moving-box"></div>



Of course it's often better just to toggle a class that encapsulates your css, hopefully this answers the question you had. If you need any clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

here getComputedStyles will read all styles. that's sort of unnecessary right just to check one single property. @OMiShah comment will be easier than this I guess.

@VikasAcharya I mean your browser will read all the styles and make them all available through getComputedStyles. If you're concerned about a performance issue, I don't imagine the overhead of checking the computed styles object will make a difference in comparison to checking the existence of a class. There are many ways to accomplish the same task.

@VikasAcharya Note that getComputedStyle despite it's name doesn't compute anything on its own. The getters on the returned (live) CSSStyleDeclaration object will cause the computation. Depending on what property is gotten it may either cause a recalc of all the elements in the DOM (worst case, like width etc.), or just the ones above in the node tree (for inheriting properties), and might even cause no more calculations than just the one needed.

As others have already pointed out, you can just use a simple if condition to check for the existence of a particular style. If you look for the existence of a color in an inline style, it'd be:
if (element.style.color) { /* elided */ }

The below example uses exactly this in toggleStyle:


const hasStyles = document.querySelector('#has-styles'); // element has inline styles set
const noStyles = document.querySelector('#no-styles');   // element has no inline styles set

const toggleStyle = (el, style, value) => {
  if (el.style[style]) {                                 // if an inline style is set...
    el.style[style] = '';                                // ... remove it
  } else {
    el.style[style] = value;                             // ... otherwise add it
  } 
};

toggleStyle(hasStyles, 'border', '1px solid blue');
toggleStyle(noStyles, 'border', '1px solid blue');
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
<div id="has-styles" style="background:red;border:1px solid blue">Has styles</div>
<div id="no-styles">No styles</div>



Be aware that this only works for elements which have a inline styles set. For checking agains a computed style (i. e. one that's set via a .css file or embedded styles), you need something more elaborated (see the answer from async await).

const toggleStyle = (el, style, value) => el.style[style] = el.style[style] ? '' : value;

Use getComputedStyle method.
<div id="myDiv" style="border:1px solid white; width:20px; height: 100px">....</div>

<script>
    // step 1 - Retrieve the element
    let element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    
    // step 2 - Get the computed style of the element
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    
    // step 3 - Check if the border property exists
    if (style.border) {
        // If border exists, remove it
        element.style.removeProperty("border");
        console.log("Border removed");
    } else {
        // If border does not exist, add it
        element.style.border = '1px solid white';
        console.log("Border added");
    }
</script>

